# Call Async function from within HTML mount

Tags: javascript, promise

So I had to turn a function `async` and now I can't call it without getting errors. THis works:

```
$('#my-obj').html(
'<li>' +
   '<a href="#"></a>'
   + myFunction("parameter") +
   '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>' +
   ...
)
```

Turned my function asynced:

```
async function myFunction() {
   //Do some stuff
   return myString;
}
```

The problem is: It's working but returning my string wraped by a `promise`. So I tried to do what I've doing so far:

```
$('#my-obj').html(
'<li>' +
   '<a href="#"></a>'
   + await myFunction("parameter") +
   '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>' +
   ...
)
```

Doesn't work. It says there are invalid characters on that line.
How to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `await` in an `async` function. With an `async` function, it works:

```js
async function myFunction(x) {
  return x.toUpperCase();
}

(async () => {
  $('#my-obj').html(
  '<li>' +
     '<a href="#"></a>'
     + await myFunction("parameter") +
     '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>' +
     '</li>'
  );
})()
.catch(error => {
  // Handle error
});
```

```html
<ul id="my-obj"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks for the explanation. Are you sure the end of the async function is right ? I'm geting some error. What is that last `()` before the catch for ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - To call the function. That's an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) using an arrow function. Since the function is an `async` function, its return value is a promise (which is why I have the `.catch` on it).